# How to merge changes in local repository with ticket which is created for development repository in GIT?

Tags: git

Thanks in advance for the Answers and i am new to GIT. I have remote directory in GIT example named as 5575 and it has ticket called as "ticket1". This ticket has some commit but it is not yet merged with "Master" 5575 repository. I have cloned the 5575 "Master" repository and i have made some changes in local repository. I have committed against the ticket "ticket1" but when i try to PUSH the changes to ticket "ticket1", I am getting the error says ***"error: failed to push some refs to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
"*** 
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: the message is clear: your local branch is behind the remote branch. Github will never let you override an existing branch unless you do it directly in github

Comment: How to merge the remote branch into local branch?

Comment: basic git: `git fetch origin` `git merge remote-branch`. I suggest you first read this https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1

Comment: I tried with above commands and getting the same issue.

Comment: I have some updates against the file in the remote branch and how to merge the changes in the remote branch with my local branch. Please assist..